# Cholesky matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given the Cholesky decomposition $U U^T = A$ of a positive definite matrix, is there anything known about $U$ itself? It is obviously not symmetric and also not positive definite but does it have any special properties about the trace, determinant, eigenvalues, diagonal dominant, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Choleksy Factorization from Trefethan is given where $$ A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m} $$ is Hermitian positive definite then we have 
$$ A  = R^{*}R,  r_{jj} > 0 $$ where R is an upper triangular matrix.

Does it have any special properties?

It is pretty well known that determinant of triangular matrices is the product of the diagonal that is the following

$$ det(R) = \prod_{i=1}^{m} r_{ii} $$

Also one should note that eigenvalues of the triangular matrix are entries on the main diagonal. Then we have the following. 
$$ det(R) = \prod_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_{i}$$

Also the following

$$ tr(R) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_{i} $$

Comment: Thanks, but it appears to me that R has similar properties as a positive definite matrix. Somewhat surprising for me but doesn't make it less true.
Do you happen to know wether the r_ij elements have special properties given that rjj > 0?

Comment: Aside from the non-obvious way it is factored. I don't particularly.

Answer (score -1):

The definition I know of Cholesky decomposition (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) for instance) includes that $U$ is a lower triangular matrix with real and positive diagonal entries. So from here you can deduce information about determinant and eigenvalues.